# Is it detrimental to have a large collection of unused images in the WordPress media library?

Tags: wordpress, media, bluehost

I have a large collection of unused images and videos in the WordPress media library. Some of them have been imported when I setup the theme, and some of them are simply unused. Besides the clutter, are there any other disadvantages to having multiple unused media files in the Media Library?

For example, does it affect the speed of loading?
I have tried to analyze this using various site-speed tools such as Pingdom, GTmetrix, etc. and they have not indicated in any "straightforward" way that the website load-speed could be impacted because of the huge collection of unused media files.

This is the site that I am working on:
http://villacasuarina.com
It is hosted with bluehost and CDN is enabled through CloudFlare

It is setup with Wordpress and most of the media is in:
https://villacasuarina.com/wp-content/uploads/

Comment: It doesn't directly affect the performance at the start but eventually it will as the space of your hosting is wasted and also the the server usage matters. So i suggest you to clean up the unused data time to time. If you don't It will also be painful process when you are migrating or taking backup.

Comment: How to clean up my images?  I know I have many duplicates, but won't deleting them break links?